# How do I save directory information from os.execute("dir") into a string?

Tags: lua

Is it possible to save the directory info obtained from `os.execute("dir")` into a string form?

So in the directory `<DELL>` I have the files `info.txt` and `readme.txt`.  I want to use `os.execute("dir")` and have the files `info.txt` and `readme.txt` saved into string `DIR`.  So I guess the entire string would read something like `DELL; info.txt, readme.txt`.

Comment: The output of `os.execute("dir")` isn't simply `DELL; info.txt, readme.txt`

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I'm sorry about that.  That wasn't what I meant it would actually say, I just wanted to make sure others would understand what I was trying to do.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

No, but using [`io.popen`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) should work.

> #### `io.popen (prog [, mode])`
>
> This function is system dependent and is not available on all platforms.
>
> Starts program `prog` in a separated process and returns a file handle that you can use to read data from this program (if `mode` is `"r"`, the default) or to write data to this program (if `mode` is `"w"`).

```
local p = io.popen( "dir", "r" )
local output = p:read "*a"
p:close( )
-- and use output
```

Comment: YES!!  Thank you so much!  Now all I need to do is just isolate the parts I need.  Thank you!

Comment: @Brandon: You can either use string.match() for that, or simply use "dir/b" command (instead of "dir") to have only the filenames returned by the command with no extra 'garbage'.

Comment: And it just keeps getting better and better!

Comment: @tonypdmtr - That's not enough.  After that, filenames must be converted from OEM codepage. Or use `cmd /C chcp xxx | dir/b`